# Continuation of a smooth function, whose every derivative is strictly monotonic

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, smoothness

Let $f$ be a function defined on $(-\infty, a]$ such that every derivative of $f$ is strictly monotonic. Does it guarantee uniqueness of a smooth continuation $g$ of $f$ to the whole real line, where every derivative of $g$ is strictly monotonic?
If not, what condition should we use so that the continuation is unique but other than requiring $f$ to be analytic?

Comment: At first, one may have a knee-jerk reflex about smooth non-zero functions which have all derivative $0$ at $0$, and the related functions. It's not quite that simple thought.

Comment: Why the votes to close? This seems a very reasonable question to me. (After the edits anyway.)

Comment: What about $f(x)=1/x$ (and $a=-1$)?

Comment: @ACL: OP does not ask about existence but about uniqueness.

Answer (score 6):

EDITED. The following theorem of Bernstein answers the question:

> If $f$ is infinitely differentiable on an interval and no derivative changes sign, then $f$ is analytic.

Your condition that all derivatives are monotone of course implies that none
of them changes sign.
Therefore, if such a function is extended on a larger interval with
preservation of the property that no derivative changes sign, then such an extension is unique.

S. Bernstein, Sur la définition et les propriétés des fonctions analytiques d'une
variable réelle, Math. Ann. vol. 75 (1914) pp. 449-468.

Here is a link: http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN00226580X
The theorem is stated in section 5. Actually it is much stronger than I stated.

A survey of the later results on the topic is

Polya, G. [On the zeros of the derivatives of a function and its analytic character](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183505036). Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 49, (1943). 178–191.

Comment: Your comment is interesting, but I require all derivatives strictly monotone - it does not mean all derivatives non- negative. (e.g. ln(x) ).

Comment: Also, there is a question whether a smooth continuation is unique if we require all derivatives to be strictly monotonic.

Comment: exp(-x) is a better example of a smooth function whose all derivatives are strictly monotonic but some are negative, some positive.

Comment: @Tomasz Grzybowski: I edited my answer.

Comment: I am surprised by this result. I would love it to be true, but I have serious doubts. I think it may be a major problem to come up with a counterexample. Is it possible to concisely sketch a proof?

Comment: I commented regarding the result which you mention.

Comment: @H. Tomasz Grzybowski: Polya in his survey says that people in 1914 were also surprised. Why don't you just read Bernstein's paper? This journal is available on Internet.

Comment: There is also a Russian translation in Bernstein's Collected papers (also available on I-net) for those who do not read French.

Comment: @H.TomaszGrzybowski Once the result is stated, the proof becomes an exercise in the Taylor formula: use positivity to show that the Taylor series at a given point converges to $f$ on its domain definition.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked at the article. The author requires derivatives from n-th to kn-th to be different from zero, where k is fixed and n is arbitrary. Clearly this implies that all derivatives have to be different from zero. But then he comments that if we just require all derivatives to be different from zero, then f(.) is not necessarily analytic.

Comment: Actually the requirement on drivatives from n-th to kn-th with arbitrary n is equivalent to the requirement on all the derivatives.

Comment: I got it. The result seems true and it is beautiful.

Comment: But I have doubts - Bernstein quotes a result by Pringsheim, according to which existence of numbers M and R such that absolute value of n-th derivative of f(.) at any point of interval (a,b) is smaller than M*R^n*n! is SUFFICIENT for analyticity of f(.) on (a,b). I do not see why it would be sufficient - the remainder in the Taylor formula should go to 0 as n goes to infinity.